# Insert or update data using cte_results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query having cte with number of columns, I want to insert a record if `ID` from the results of that query does not exist in table that I am inserting, or if the `ID` exists I want to update data using that `ID`.

So far I have tried this:

```
WITH cte_base as(
SELECT DISTINCT ID, statusID
FROM testtable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_base

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Newtable WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM cte_base))
UPDATE newtable
SET statusID = 2
WHERE Newtable.ID = cte_base.ID

ELSE
INSERT INTO newtable(ID, statusID)
SELECT ID, statusID 
FROM cte_base
WHERE Newtable.ID <> cte_base.ID
```

I have to run this query against live data, hence I would like to know if my logic is correct.

Comment: you cannot do this, use temp tables

Comment: If you could add a formalized question in there, also you might provide some data, and DDL for the testtable / newtable to make it a bit easier on those of us trying to assist.

Comment: Looks like you want a MERGE statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: @AnthonyHancock thanks for the reference.. I will try this and if it doesn't work I will add DDL for testtable and newtable.

Comment: @Aureate if that worked for you, I'd appreciate you accepting my provided answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I accepted it few days back. Did that still not reflect on your account?

Comment: @Aureate, sorry I guess I missed the notification; I see the check mark now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic merge example based on your provided code.

```
MERGE INTO NewTable AS T
USING
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID,statusID
    FROM testtable
) AS S
ON S.ID = T.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN SET
    T.StatusID = 2
WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT (ID,statusID)
    VALUES (S.ID,S.statusID)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do?

```
EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM cte_base)
```

If cte_base has any records that will be true every time

That is no different than

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, statusID
FROM testtable
```

And will be true every time if there are any records in testtable

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the comments section?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock not according to the meta, because it improves the question